# can someone explain rates to me? (spec. question inside)

Tags: fractions

i noticed that i've been getting this type of question consistently wrong, in the new sat prep. i'm not sure what kind of problem it exactly is either, so i could not find an explanation. i would really appreciate it if you could explain this whole concept, if that's possible? thank you so much!

(1/x) + (4/x) = (1/72)

Cities and towns use water treatment facilities to remove contaminants from surface water and groundwater. Suppose a town has a treatment plant  but decides to build a second, more efficient facility. New treatment plants can filter the water in the reservoir four times as quickly as the older facility. Working together, the two facilities can filter all the water in the reservoir in 72 hours. The equation above represents the scenario. Which of the following describes what the term (1/x) represents?

Comment: A rate is amount/time.  So $\frac{1}{x} ~= \frac{\mbox{1 reservoir of water}}{\mbox{$x$ hours}}$ and $\frac{4}{x} ~=\frac{\mbox{4 reservoirs of water}}{\mbox{$x$ hours}}$.  Rates are additive, so the total rate of filtering water if we use both filters together is the sum of the individual rates, and that must equal $\frac{1}{72} ~=\frac{\mbox{1 reservoir of water}}{\mbox{$72$ hours}}$.  Overall $1/x$ is the rate that hte slow filter uses to filter water (in units of reservoirs/hour).  You could have just called it $r$, and written the equation $r + 4r = 1/72$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you did not give the choices at the end. But it looks as if 1/x represents the fraction of the reservoir that the older facility can filter in one hour. (Together the two facilities fill 1/72 of the reservoir in one hour).